# Советы по написанию вопроса вылезают на футер

Tags: дефект

...при прокрутке вниз.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а почему это дефект?

Comment: @AntonMenshov: Неаккуратно как-то (ц) Дизайнер внутри меня протестует.